# Application communicates with database on iOS simulator but not on device

Tags: ios, mysql, swift, database

Good evening,

I have a table view that gets populated with data from my local MySQL database. I'm using MAMP along with PHPmyadmin.

It works perfectly fine on the simulator, as you can see:

[Working Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zodu0.png)

However, when I try to run it on my iPhone device, it doesn't load anything:

[Not working Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dr6yU.png)

What could be the cause for that? I don't really get the difference between the simulator and the device.

The code looks like this:

```
 let url: URL = URL(string: urlPath)!
    let defaultSession = Foundation.URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)

    let task = defaultSession.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print("Failed to download data")
        }else {
            print("Data downloaded")
            self.parseJSON(data!)
        }
```

It prints "Data Downloaded" when on simulator and "Failed to download data" on the device.
I'm using Xcode 9 and Swift 4.

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: What is your URL? Aren't you using localhost instead of the IP address/external URL of your server?

Comment: <ip-address> look like a private subnet of a network, could it be that you WiFi is on another subnet?

Comment: It would be usefull to print out the error description to get more information about what is causing the failure. Likely a network issue

Comment: I'm indeed using my localhost @DávidPásztor, here's my URL:
 let urlPath: String = "http://localhost:8888/service.php" 

What do I need to change ? 

There's no error description :/

Comment: @SébastienBenigni you need to change `localhost` to whatever your server's IP address is

Comment: It works ! How could I be so stupid lmao, it seemed so obvious >< thanks a lot for helping me !!